# Can we get the subset from the dynamic solution of partition?

Tags: java, arrays, partitioning

I want to print the two subsets of a set which give same sum which is basically the partition problem. I am using the dynamic solution for the [partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem). The problem is that it returns a Boolean answer only (whether the set can be partitioned or not). How can I get the subset from the 2d table which is used in dynamic programming?

How can I backtrace the 2D array used to get elements?

```
public class SubsetSum {
    public boolean partition(int arr[]) {
        int sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            sum += arr[i];
        }

        if (sum % 2 != 0) {
            return false;
        }

        sum = sum / 2;
        boolean[][] T = new boolean[arr.length + 1][sum + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++) {
            T[i][0] = true;
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= sum; j++) {
                if (j - arr[i - 1] >= 0) {
                    T[i][j] = T[i - 1][j - arr[i - 1]] || T[i - 1][j];
                } else {
                    T[i][j] = T[i-1][j];
                }
            }
        }

        return T[arr.length][sum];
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SubsetSum ss = new SubsetSum();
        int arr[] = {1, 3, 5, 5, 2, 1, 1, 6};
        System.out.println(ss.partition(arr));
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post result what you want. its not clear what do you want to do.

Comment: I want the result containing all the elements selected to make the sum equal to sum/2 , if the partition method returns true. The set of element selected in the 2d array is one of the 2 subsets which have same sum.
For eg: 
If arr [ ] = {1,2,3,4}. This method returns true by selecting  {2,3}. I needed a code so that I could print the subset selected i.e {2,3}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer. Posting it in case someone got the same question. 
If the partition method returns true. S1 is an ArrayList of Integer type. It will store elements of one of the Subset say Subset1. Rest of the elements in the given array will be the part of subset2.

```
if(T[input.length][total])
    {
        int i=input.length-1;
        int j=total;
        while(i!=0||j!=0)
        {
            if(T[i][j])
                i--;
            else
            {
                S1.add(input[i]);
                j-=input[i];
            }
        }
 }
```